# OWA 2003 404 error only for calender

Tags: outlook-web-app

We have a exchange 2003 published through isa 2006 , for every user this is working fine except one who receives a 404 error every time they try and view details of the calender, I have cloned their account which work's fine.

How do I troubleshoot or resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

A 404 error is strange. I've seen problems with appointments that were related to local date/time time zone differences.

Is this happening independently on which machine the user runs the browser?

Do you run IIS URLScan on the ISA/Exchange Server? If yes, then maybe something in the user's name (in the URL) it's causing the problem.

Comment: It happens on any browser, any machine , internal and external. the users name is normal no symbols , the appointments have no strange characters. no URLscan. We also have alternative access with a secondary isa and front end exchange  with the same results.

Answer (score 1):

A coworker of mine was troubleshooting a similar issue recently, and migrating the user's mailbox to another Exchange database (on the same server) ended up correcting it. The problem occurred when trying to access some public folder calendars, and the public folder store on the database was set correctly. We have no real data as to the cause, but suspect some data within the mailbox was corrupt or out of date and was reset to the new database template during the migration process. It's only happened once to that one user, so unfortunately we couldn't justify investing more time to determine why.